# Converting a file into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file with four different sets of data on one line.
State Qtr Year Index

I want to convert the text file into a dictionary with class instances. 
When I run the module the error returned is: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your file content and what you tried to achieve what you want

Comment: File content example:
AK 1975 1 62.62
AK 1975 2 63.40
AK 1975 3 66.60
AK 1975 4 67.91
AK 1976 1 70.45
AK 1976 2 71.83
AK 1976 3 72.52
AK 1976 4 73.87
AK 1977 1 80.26
AK 1977 2 73.68
AK 1977 3 79.76
AK 1977 4 78.69
AK 1978 1 77.10
AK 1978 2 86.36
AK 1978 3 87.39
AK 1978 4 87.19
AK 1979 1 89.64

AK 1979 2 99.09



.Each AK is on it own line with the 3 data values following it seperated by a tab.

Comment: @Khalidsaleh please edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: What Im trying to achieve:
[QuarterHPI( year=1991, qtr=1, index=100.0 ), QuarterHPI( year=1991, qtr=2,
index=99.48 ), QuarterHPI( year=1991, qtr=3, index=100.05 )]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it would be easier just to use `pickle.dump()` and save a dictionary into a file first instead of writing your data straight into the file. For example:

```
import pickle

saveData = {'data here' : 12345, 'more data' : 54321}
file = open("filename.txt")
pickle.dump(saveData, file)
file.close()
```

Then, to read your file again, you can simply write

```
file = open("filename.txt")
saveData = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```